# Can I add non-Id fields in join table in Many to Many Relationship?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, orm, jpa-2.1

I have *many to many* relationship between `Person` and `Address` tables.

Person:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PERSON_MTM", schema = "Examples")
public class Person 
{
@Id
@Column(name = "PERSON_ID")
private String personId;

@Column(name = "PERSON_NAME")
private String personName;

@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "PERSON_ADDRESS", schema = "KunderaExamples",joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "PERSON_ID") }, inverseJoinColumns = {  @JoinColumn(name = "ADDRESS_ID") })
private Set<AddressMTM> addresses;

//setters and getters

}
```

Address:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ADDRESS_MTM", schema = "Examples")
public class Address
{
@Id
@Column(name = "ADDRESS_ID")
private String addressId;

@Column(name = "STREET")
private String street;

// setters and getters

}
```

I have a **joinTable** named `PERSON_ADDRESS`.

- Can I add non-Id fields to join-table?
- Are there any JPA constraints in it?

> Note: My question is not in terms of `Hibernate`. I am asking on
>   behalf of `JPA 2.1`

Comment: What do you mean by JPA constraints in it?

Comment: @swinkler JPA constraints mean if there is any documentation that suggests or forces to use only Id fields.

Comment: I added the API link to JoinTable/joinColumns where you can see that there are no constraints from JPA.

Comment: The columns of a join table will be the id columns of both sides. That's all there is. If you want "other" columns then you create an intermediate entity (as shown in many other posts on the subject on Stackoverflow)

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple [JoinColumms](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/JoinTable.html#joinColumns()), e.g. including PERSON_NAME (if this makes sense for your logic)

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(
    name = "PERSON_ADDRESS", 
    schema = "KunderaExamples",
    joinColumns = { 
      @JoinColumn(name="PERSON_NAME"),
      @JoinColumn(name = "PERSON_ID") }, 
    inverseJoinColumns = {  
      @JoinColumn(name = "ADDRESS_ID") })
private Set<AddressMTM> addresses;
```